# When python creates new objects in memory

Tags: python, variable-assignment, python-internals

In the following example Python uses the same integer object in the memory for all three names x, y and z in the namespace

```
def main():
    x = 0
    y = 0
    z = 0
    print(x,y,z)
    print(x is y is z)
    y = 2
    print(x,y,z)
    print(x is y)
    print(z is y)
    print(x is z)

if __name__ == "__main__":main()
```

Output:

```
0 0 0
True
0 2 0
False
False
True
```

Why Python doesn't use the same tuple object here ( yes it is the choice of language designers but why) and a better questin to ask is when python creates new objects in memory

```
def main():
    a = 1, 2, 3
    b = (1, 2, 3)
    c = 1, 2, 3

    print(type(a) == type(b))
    print(a == b)
    print(a is b)
    print(a == c)
    print(a is c)

if __name__ == "__main__":main()
```

Output:

```
True
True
False
True
False
```

Comment: Can you please not dump pictures of code in your question? There's always the sterling option of just _pasting_ it.

Comment: When Python creates a new object is implementation-dependent. In practice, string literals are reused, strings passed to `intern()` are reused, small integers are reused, the empty tuple is reused. There is a tradeoff between reusing all immutable objects, and keeping track of which immutable objects are available for reuse.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: The questioner knows the difference between `is` and `==`. The question is about why the tuples are different objects, not why `is` and `==` report different things.

Comment: @PM2Ring thanks man i will do from now on

Comment: Instead of doing it from now on, if you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45763675/edit) now your question it will be more useful for future visitors.

Comment: @ayhan i removed the images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a literal that represents a mutable object, every evaluation of the literal must generate a new object.

For a literal that represents an immutable object, whether a new object is created comes down to arbitrary implementation details. It could have chosen to use the same tuple. It could use the same tuple in a future release, or in a different Python implementation. Your example actually *does* reuse tuples if you call `main` repeatedly, but different tuples for `a`, `b`, and `c`. You shouldn't rely on it being one way or another.

If you want to see the particular implementation details for this case, the [CPython bytecode compiler](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Python/compile.c) ordinarily merges equivalent constants together in a code object (the mechanism involves a dict, with some extra work to keep things like `1.0` and `1` from merging), but the [peephole optimization pass](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Python/peephole.c#L170) that precomputes the 3 tuples occurs in a postprocessing phase that doesn't have the deduplication machinery in place.

Comment: Thanks man i need the logic behind things it makes me a better coder actually i thought the same and i expected  Python reuse the tuple in the memory i will accept this answer if there is no other answer